# Why do the gridview still appears even if the datasource is empty?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
                                            <asp:GridView ID="gv_Info" runat="server" Width="1240px" BorderWidth="1px"
                                            CellPadding="4" BorderColor="Gray" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#f6f6eb"
                                            BackColor="#F3372A" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="false">
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" Wrap="false" />
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                                       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAsset" runat="server" />
                                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="d" HeaderText="ATag">
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="c" HeaderText="Description">
                                                    <HeaderStyle />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="a" HeaderText="AType">
                                                    <HeaderStyle />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="q" HeaderText="ID">
                                                    <HeaderStyle />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>


                    gv_InfoAssetsByParams.DataSource = ArrayAssets.ToList()
                    gv_InfoAssetsByParams.DataBind()
```

but when ArrayAssets is empty I want to make the gridview empty. SO I do this,

```
            If ArrayAssets.Length > 0 Then
                gv_Info.DataSource = ArrayAssets.ToList()
                gv_Info.DataBind()


            Else
              gv_Info.DataSource = ArrayAssets.ToList()
                gv_Info.DataBind()
            End If
```

But it still appears even if i assign `Nothing` to the data source. How do I make it empty with headers?

Comment: use `gv_Info.DataSource = null;` in `else`

Comment: Why do you have the same code in the If and the Else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP has a property called ShowHeader when empty. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx)
                                                                                         Set `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"`, that should work.

Comment: @scaryghost Why did you except the answer if it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, you are repeating the same thing in your IF statement.

I tried to replicate your problem on my end, and indeed if the datasource is empty the grid is not visible. I think you should look at the properties of your gridview and go from there. As well, I recommend using a repeater for more control of the visibility and layout when displaying data.